# Why is this re-direct not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Controller

```
  def subscribe
    @mailchimp_list_id = "01d4743206"
    @gb = Gibbon::API.new
    @email = params[:email]
      @gb.lists.subscribe({
      :id => @mailchimp_list_id,
      :email => @email,
      :double_optin => false,
      :send_welcome => false
    })
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Whats up"
  end
```

View

```
    <%= form_tag('/posts/subscribe', method: "post", id: "subscribe", remote: "true") do%>
        <div class="large-18 columns text-right mailer">
        <%= email_field(:email, :email, {id: "mailersub", placeholder: "Enter your email"}) %>
        </div>
        <div class="large-6 columns text-right mailer">
            <%= submit_tag("Submit", id: "mailersubmit") %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

All I really want to happen is for the mailchimp process to be completed and then then it re-directs to a path with a notice. The controller and view is for a mailer list form, upon submit I would like this to occur.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: any error or server logs sharing possible?

Answer (score 0):

remote: true do ajax request, it can not redirect. u have to remove remote: true OR at js .on ajax:success do location.url = '/'

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer, you have to render js inside the controller and inline javascript can be used to redirection:

```
def subscribe
    @mailchimp_list_id = "01d4743206"
    @gb = Gibbon::API.new
    @email = params[:email]
      @gb.lists.subscribe({
      :id => @mailchimp_list_id,
      :email => @email,
      :double_optin => false,
      :send_welcome => false
    })
    flash[:notice] = "Whats up"
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :js => "/" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: oh try this:
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js { render :js => "/" }
        end